# error: the method `set_bit` exists for type `u8`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied (works for usize?)

Tags: rust

I'm working on some bit manipulation code that converts primitive integers into a newtype called `struct Bits(Vec<bool>)` where the bools in the vec each represent a single bit.  I implemented the From trait to convert from Bits back to usize and it worked perfectly.  I changed the same implementation of From to convert from Bits back to u8 and it complains about u8 not satisfying my trait bounds for things like BitAnd even though u8 definitely does have an implementation for BitAnd.  In fact, u8 and usize implement BitAnd via the exact same call to a macro in Rust's library.  The trait bounds in question are from a blanket implementation from my BitMan trait.  What am I not understanding that makes the usize work fine but the u8 not even compile?

The full error and notes I get is:

```
   error[E0599]: the method `set_bit` exists for type `u8`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:131:24 
    |
131 |             new_u8.set_bit(index, Bit(current_bit)).unwrap();
    |                    ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `u8` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
note: trait bound `&mut u8: BitAnd` was not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:168:8
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
167 | where
168 |     T: BitAnd<Output = Self>
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `<&mut u8 as BitAnd>::Output = &mut u8`
      `<&u8 as BitAnd>::Output = &u8`
   --> src\lib.rs:168:15
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
167 | where
168 |     T: BitAnd<Output = Self>
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: trait bound `&mut u8: BitOr` was not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:169:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
169 |         + BitOr<Output = Self>
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `<&mut u8 as BitOr>::Output = &mut u8`
      `<&u8 as BitOr>::Output = &u8`
   --> src\lib.rs:169:17
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
169 |         + BitOr<Output = Self>
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: trait bound `&mut u8: Not` was not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:170:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
170 |         + Not<Output = Self>
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `<&mut u8 as Not>::Output = &mut u8`
      `<&u8 as Not>::Output = &u8`
   --> src\lib.rs:170:15
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
170 |         + Not<Output = Self>
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: trait bound `&mut u8: Shl` was not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:171:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
171 |         + Shl<Output = Self>
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `<&mut u8 as Shl>::Output = &mut u8`
      `<&u8 as Shl>::Output = &u8`
   --> src\lib.rs:171:15
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
171 |         + Shl<Output = Self>
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `&mut u8: num::Zero`
      `&u8: num::Zero`
   --> src\lib.rs:173:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
173 |         + Zero
    |           ^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `&mut u8: One`
      `&u8: One`
   --> src\lib.rs:174:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
174 |         + One
    |           ^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `&mut u8: From<usize>`
      `&u8: From<usize>`
      `u8: From<usize>`
   --> src\lib.rs:175:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
175 |         + From<usize>
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: trait bound `&mut u8: Clone` was not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:176:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
176 |         + Clone
    |           ^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
```

_

```
pub struct Bits(Vec<bool>);

impl<T> BitMan for T
where
T: BitAnd<Output = Self>
    + BitOr<Output = Self>
    + Not<Output = Self>
    + Shl<Output = Self>
    + Sized
    + Zero
    + One
    + From<usize>
    + Clone
    + PartialEq,
{
    fn set_bit(mut self, index: usize, bit: Bit) -> Result<Bit, BitManError> {
        if index > size_of::<Self>() {
            return Err(BitManError::OutOfBounds(format!(
                "Index {:?} is larger than total size {:?}.",
                index,
                size_of::<Self>()
            )));
        }
        if bit.0 {
            let mask: Self = Self::one();
            let mask: Self = mask << (size_of::<Self>() - index).into();
            self = self & !mask.clone();
            return Ok(Bit(self & mask != Self::zero()));
        } else {
            let mask: Self = Self::one();
            let mask: Self = mask << (size_of::<Self>() - index).into();
            self = self | mask.clone();
            return Ok(Bit(self & mask != Self::zero()));
        }
    }
}

impl From<Bits> for usize {
    fn from(bits_to_convert: Bits) -> Self {
        if bits_to_convert.0.len() > size_of::<usize>() {
            let shortened_bits: Bits = Bits(
                bits_to_convert.0
                    [(bits_to_convert.0.len() - size_of::<usize>())..bits_to_convert.0.len()]
                    .to_vec(),
            );
            usize::from(shortened_bits)
        } else {
            let mut new_usize: usize = Default::default();
            for (index, current_bit) in bits_to_convert.0.clone().into_iter().enumerate() {
                new_usize.set_bit(index, Bit(current_bit)).unwrap();
            }
            if bits_to_convert.0.len() < size_of::<usize>() {
                new_usize = new_usize >> size_of::<usize>() - bits_to_convert.0.len();
            }
            new_usize
        }
    }
}

impl From<Bits> for u8 {
    fn from(bits_to_convert: Bits) -> Self {
        if bits_to_convert.0.len() > size_of::<u8>() {
            let shortened_bits: Bits = Bits(
                bits_to_convert.0
                    [(bits_to_convert.0.len() - size_of::<u8>())..bits_to_convert.0.len()]
                    .to_vec(),
            );
            u8::from(shortened_bits)
        } else {
            let mut new_u8: u8 = Default::default();
            for (index, current_bit) in bits_to_convert.0.clone().into_iter().enumerate() {
                new_u8.set_bit(index, Bit(current_bit)).unwrap();
            }
            if bits_to_convert.0.len() < size_of::<u8>() {
                new_u8 = new_u8 >> size_of::<u8>() - bits_to_convert.0.len();
            }
            new_u8
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the full error to the question.

Comment: @EricEvans There should be more text in the error which tells exactly which trait bounds were not satisfied.

Comment: @Dogbert There are notes that specify those.  I will add those too.

Comment: @EricEvans hi, please provide a [mcve] that can be used to test. It's very difficult to test something that cannot be pasted into a compiler to help with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite sizeable but I'll pick out one particular problematic portion and highlight it:

```
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `&mut u8: From<usize>`
      `&u8: From<usize>`
      `u8: From<usize>`
   --> src\lib.rs:175:11
    |
166 | impl<T> BitMan for T
    |         ------     -
...
175 |         + From<usize>
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
```

When the compiler sees `new_u8.set_bit(...)`, it will try `u8`, `&u8`, and `&mut u8` to try to match a trait implementation. But as you can see above, *none* of these types implement `From<usize>`. You can see this better if you call the trait method explicitly for the implementation you expect using the fully qualified syntax:

```
<u8 as BitMan>::set_bit(new_u8, ...)
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: From<usize>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:87:17
   |
87 |                 <u8 as BitMan>::set_bit(new_u8, index, Bit(current_bit)).unwrap();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<usize>` is not implemented for `u8`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <u8 as From<Bits>>
             <u8 as From<NonZeroU8>>
             <u8 as From<bool>>
             <f32 as From<i16>>
           and 73 others
```

Based on your wording, I'm guessing you're assuming it'd be implemented for `u8`, however `usize` can represent way more values than can fit in a `u8`, such conversion would be lossy. The `TryFrom` trait is used for conversions that can fail. Regardless, you should probably use `T: Shl<usize, Output = Self>` instead and drop the `.into()`s and `From` constraint. This [compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a33e1173ecaffb1953cf3c68bea674a).

You should probably also change it to change `self` by mutable reference. Because you're passing `self` by value, right now it'd simply copy the `usize`/`u8`, modify it within the function, and then do nothing with it; it won't modify the original value.

Comment: I had not realized that I could specify the rhs type for Shl.  That does make the whole situation simpler.  I had also not realized that the From<usize> being missing would cause the compiler to complain about so many other impl's missing.